# How do I implement relationship of dropdown lists

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a form something like this on my drop down list.

```
OPTION A
 - AA
 - AB
 - AC

OPTION B
 - BA
 - BB
 - BC

OPTION C
 - CA
 - CB
 - CC

OPTION D
 - DA
 - DB
 - DC
```

- First show `OPTION A`. If `OPTION A`
  `selected` then show `OPTION B`
- ...
- ...
- If `OPTION C` `selected` then
  show `OPTION D`

There have a any jQuery plugin for this? Let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been done a [thousand <sub><sup>(times 744)</sup></sub> times over](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20cascading%20OR%20dependent%20dropdown%20OR%20select).

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-cascade/
- http://jsatt.blogspot.com/2010/01/cascading-select-boxes-using-jquery.html
- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DependentSelect

Comment: Thank you so much for the `cascading` & `dependent`.